# Flutter Firestore StreamBuilder On A Document Array/List

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Alright, so in Firestore i have an collection called 'user_profile' which have a document with the users uid and the document has an array of posts with data in them:

Like this:

```
Collection          Document          Documents data (array) 
user_posts          users uid         [0: {...}, 1: {...}, 2: {...} ...]
```

How can I set up a StreamBuilder that retrieves this data and then build it in a ListView.builder?

I have a working solution where I am not working with a document with the users uid and an array with the posts. Where I instead have each post as an document with data in it. And then I can build this into an list and use it in a ListView.builder.

So the question is, how can I instead do this with an Document that has an array in it, like i described above.

Thanks!

Comment: It's totally up to you, but I might suggest structuring user posts differently. I would separate the Array data into a collection like: `user_posts/users_uid/posts/documents` . Basically creating a sub-collection for each users uid.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the suggestion, I took up on that offer and it works a lot better/makes more sense to do it that way. But i'm still having trouble creating a stream to this subcollection. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Never mind, solved it. It was problem with my code that made me blind, where my uid was null when trying to fetch the data from that uid. Thanks for the restructuring tips! Made everything much clearer now. :)